# Looking for an Excel COUNTA equivalent for a DataTable VB.Net

Tags: excel, vb.net, datatable

I'm trying to find an equivalent to the Excel CountA function for a DataTable.

```
       'This code works for searching through a range of columns in Excel
        If xlApp.WorksheetFunction.CountA(WS.Range("A" & i & ":G" & i)) > 0 Then
            DataExists = True
        End If
```

```
       'This is the code I need help with for searching though a DataTable
        If DataTbl.Rows(i).Item(0:6).ToString <> "" Then
            DataExists = True
        End If
```

Hoping someone can help with this.

Comment: There won't be an exact equivalent, but as long as you can define what "containing any type of information" means in the context of a datatable, it should be straightforward to write it yourself, possibly using Linq (which would allow you to use `Count()` on the generated sequence).

Answer (score 0):

I think you simply need a for-each loop.

```
internal static int CountForEach(this DataTable? dt)
{
    if (dt == null)
        return 0;
    int count = 0;
    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        foreach (object? o in row.ItemArray)
            if (o != DBNull.Value)
                count++;
    return count;
}
```

Usage:

```
DataTable dt = GetYourDataTable();
int countValues = dt.CountNotNullValues_ForEach();
```

This is also doable with LINQ but I think it would be slower -- I'll run some benchmarks later and update my answer.

EDIT

I added these two LINQ methods:

```
internal static int CountLinqList(this DataTable? dt)
{
    int count = 0;
    dt?.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().ToList().ForEach(row => count += row.ItemArray.Where(g => g != DBNull.Value).Count());
    return count;
}

internal static int CountLinqParallel(this DataTable? dt)
{
    ConcurrentBag<int> ints = new();
    dt?.AsEnumerable().AsParallel().ForAll(row => ints.Add(row.ItemArray.Where(g => g != DBNull.Value).Count()));
    int count = ints.Sum();
    return count;
}
```

These are the statistics obtained with BenchmarkDotNet:

[image]

I used a pseudo-randomly generated datatable of around 5.5 million rows and three columns as test.
I think these results may change with larger datatables, but for smaller (around 500k rows and less) the fastest method will probably be the simple for-each loop.

Fastest methods:

1. For each loop
2. Linq parallel
3. Linq list > for each

I'm surely not a LINQ-guru but I'd like to be, so if someone has a better LINQ implementation please let me know.
By the way, I don’t think this could be the typical LINQ use case.